# Load strategy in bidirectional association with JPA2

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have a 1:N bidirectional association between two JPA 2 entities. When I select (using JPQL request) a person, I get the list of CD affected to that person already charged.

I expected (from what I have read) that when it comes to collections (`List` in my case), by default the load type is lazy. So I expected to have a `NullPointerException` instead of an intialized list of CDs. Even if I specify the load strategy to "LAZY", I get the list of CDs initilized.

Is it enough to ask for the list (I mean to use it values), for JPA to launch a SQL resquest to get it?

Comment: Lazy loading means that the list is not fetched when the parent object is fetched, but when the relation field/property is accessed. You are accessing the property, so the CD list is fetched. Try logging the DB statements to make sure it is indeed lazily loaded.

Comment: i hv tried a logging DB and like u hv said,when it's "lazy",it doesn't fetch CD when it fetch person,just when i ask for it,it load it...THX